# View whole select options

Tags: html, css

I use `select` element with fixed width. However, when I have `option` element nested in `select`, which has quite long text, then, when this `option` is being selected, it does not get full background-width (I want the background to be 100%) and also the text is hidden.

Here is the example with the last option being hidden.

```css
.x {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<select class="x" size="4">
  <option class="y" selected>xyz</option>
  <option class="y" selected>xyz</option>
  <option class="y" selected>xyz</option>
  <option class="y" selected>xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You need multiple if you want to select more than one

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  If you want the width of the `<select>` to expand, have you tried removing the `width` from the style?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the full width using a single css property . Please add a class to solve the issue :

```
.y{
   width: fit-content;
  }
```

Using this style, you could see that the background color gets filled to the full width.